# ¿C# 9.0 es compatible con .Net Framework 4.8?

Tags: c#, .net, framework

Básicamente estoy tratando de averiguar si ¿C# 9.0 es compatible con .Net Framework 4.8?.

Estuve googleando un poco y no encontré nada relacionado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Respuesta rápida: No.

Documentación oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9

> C# 9.0 is supported on .NET 5. For more information, see C# [language versioning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).

En español:

> C# 9 es soportado en Net 5. Para mayor información, [mirar el versionamiento del lenguaje C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

Comment: C# 7.3 sí lo soporta, y C# 8 ?

Comment: Revisa este enlace: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: Esta respuesta no es del todo correcta. C# 9 es soportado completamente a partir de. NET 5 en adelante pero algunas características del lenguaje inclusive de C#10 siguen siendo posible hacerlas correr en versiones anteriores inclusive de Net Framework.